# linaro-media-create error while booting qemu/linaro

Tags: qemu, emulation, linaro

I have been trying to run linaro on qemu. I have been following this guide,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Virtual_ARM_Linux_environment#Create_the_VM_disk_image

The linaro-create-media command executes overall but gives errors in between. Thats why the next command, sudo mount is giving error of

> "invalid offset '' specified"

The linaro-create-media command is giving many such errors while fetching files,

> failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe armel
>   Packages 404 not found.

Answer (score 0):

Natty is no longer maintained, so I'm guessing that's why the repositories are down and you are getting the 404 errors.  You can use more recent versions of linaro and the hwpack: https://releases.linaro.org/15.06/ubuntu for example.  Also, I wasn't able to get that mount command to work either, but I found another way:

`sudo kpartx -avs vexpress.img`

You'll see output similar to:

`add map loop0p1 (252:2): 0 155584 linear /dev/loop0 63
add map loop0p2 (252:3): 0 6135808 linear /dev/loop0 155648`

From there you can mount the two partitions with something like this:

`sudo mkdir /mnt/loop1;sudo mkdir /mnt/loop2;sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/loop1;sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0p2 /mnt/loop2`

Even so, I didn't have much luck getting it to boot properly, but maybe you'll have better luck.

Also don't forget to umount before trying to boot:

`sudo umount /mnt/loop1;sudo umount /mnt/loop2;sudo kpartx -dvs vexpress.img`